# 'to.include' is not working where 'to.eventually.equal' is working

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, cucumber

I was trying to check whether a string is present in another string. I am using the below code:

```
expect(actualTimeZone).to.include(employee.timeZone);
```

But it is giving the below error:

> AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given

But when I tried with the below code, it is not throwing the above error:

```
expect(actualTimeZone).to.eventually.equal(employee.timeZone);
```

I am working on protractor framework with cucumber and javascript. Could someone help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the below code and it is working

`expect(actualTimeZone).to.eventually.include(employee.timeZone);`

Comment: this is because it resolves the promise

Comment: @RRR You should be accepting the answer that worked/helped, rather than accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify that the test shouldn't pass until the promise you're waiting on is resolved!

`to.include()` it does not resolve the promise

how `to.include()` is: Use the include matcher to specify that a collection includes one or more expected objects. It succeeds if any object of the given collection passes the specified matcher. This works on any object that responds to #include? (such as a string or array):

and the reason it passes with `to.eventually.include()` is it deals with promise

Promised is the eventually property. With it, you can transform any existing Chai assertion into one that acts on a promise:

if you want to.include() work why dont you simply do this may work.

```
    const arr = [actualTimeZone];
    expect(arr).to.include(employee.timeZone);
```

note : this solution is based on how your error suggest.

with this you need to resolve promise

```
it('xyz', (done) => {
  element(by.selector(element).getText())
  .then(t => {
     expect(t).then(a => to.include(y);
     done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that change doesn't make any difference to the error.And also the other one I mentioned was `to.eventually.equal` , not `to.eventually.include`

Comment: okay i forget to mention that either you return an array and resolve it with `async/await`

Comment: i updated answer and [refer this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher)